# Is there a way for me to create a bot command that does the following: (discord.js)

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

"When someone sends one message, NO-ONE can send another message until a timer is up, and then repeat." The command setup would be setting up how long the timer is, like !slow 500 would make the timer 500 seconds.

Comment: Yes. When a MESSAGE_CREATE event is received, update the permissions of the channel to deny the "send message" permission to everyone, then set a timer for the specified amount of time before allowing the permission again.

Comment: How would I make it detect and act upon a MESSAGE_CREATE event?

Comment: @Zaczer It is the same as with any of your bot's usual commands, put it in the message event. There are numerous examples on discord.js's docs.

Comment: And then how do I make it set an auto timer?

Comment: using `client.setTimeout()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

---

#### `settings.json`:

```js
{
   "slow": 500
}
```

---

#### `slow.js` (or wherever you use to trigger commands):

```js
// <time> is a placeholder for the user inputted time. Could commonly be `args[1]` or something

const settings = require('./settings.json')

settings.slow = <time> // time should be in ms, so you can use (<time> * 1000) if you want it to be in seconds, (<time> * 60000) for minutes, etc.
```

---

#### `message.js` (or wherever you want to put the `message` event):

```js
// <client> is a placeholder for the Discord.Client() object

const settings = require('./settings.json')

<client>.on('message', (message) => {
   var slowed; 
   if (slowed) return;
   slowed = true 
   setTimeout(() => {
     slowed = false
   }, settings.slow) // only make slowed falsey after specified amount of time
```